# Отсчет времени без привязки к системному времени

Tags: c#, .net

Есть класс. У него есть метод `Start()`. Необходимо в любой момент времени после выполнения метода узнать сколько прошло с тех пор времени. При этом изменение системного времени не должно влиять на результат. Операция должна быть минимально затратной.

Пока пришло в голову только использование `Stopwatch`. Но, во-первых, я не знаю насколько затратно, во-вторых, мне кажется как то неправильно использовать `System.Diagnostics` в данном случае. Не целевое использование что ли. А может это предрассудки :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте, не бойтесь, все так делают.

Answer (score 0):

Фактически Stopwatch бесплатный. Он использует [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx), которая в свою очередь может быть реализована одной командой процессора. Соответственно, разница во времени - это просто математика над двумя числами.

Другой вариант, через P/Invoke вызывать [GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411(v=vs.85).aspx), но думаю смысла в этом нет.